Attaching something to a smooth motor shaft, and handling axial load on a hollow-shaft stepper motor
I'm planning to use a stepper motor with this kind of profile

It has a hollow shaft like the picture above. I'm planning to attach something to the shaft and mount it vertically so the shaft is perpendicular to the ground. The motor's front face will face downwards.
I have two things that I'm concerned about

Since the shaft has no keyway or flat side, how do I attach anything to it? Sure, I can use some set screws to clamp something to it. But since I'm planning to mount it vertically, the attachment will always be pulled by gravity. I'm worried it will become loose over time. Is there a better way to do it? For reference, the load will be around 500g to 1 kg

Mounting something to the axle and putting it vertically will cause the motor to experience axial load. To my knowledge, this kind of load is not good for the motor's durability. How would I ease this load? I'm thinking of putting a thrust bearing on the top side and a collar on the shaft itself so it sits on top of the thrust bearing (like the picture below) to ease the load. Will this work?




please add a link to the source of the images to your post

You buy a motor that doesn't have the keyway cut all the way on the shaft (You can see the keyway in your photos).  And make sure the motor is designed with internal thrust bearings, I doubt that one is.  You can't use the motor case to hold the load.  Use sheaves if you can't find a motor that will hold the load.

Pulleys etc can be fixed with collets or "taper locks", some are just split on the centre line and clamped to the shaft.
If the shaft has an internal thread that can be used as well.
One example:

Source link https://www.ebay.com/itm/186317525243

Thanks for the suggestion! However, I think that is going to be too overkill for my case. My load is only about 500g (5N of axial load), and the max rotational load is about 10Ncm. I'm considering using keyless bushings instead. The inner part of the bushing is slotted into the motor shaft, and I'm going to find a bigger shaft to clamp to the outer shaft. Will this be strong enough?
